# Каким знаком заканчивается предложение?

Tags: пунктуация, выбор-варианта, обращение, вопросительный-знак

Пишу небольшой рассказ и забыла, как правильно ставится знак препинания в конце.
Звучит как просьба, но и как вопрос. Ещё есть обращение к собеседнику. И я запуталась, как правильно поставить знак препинания.

*Позволь проводить тебя, моя госпожа.*

Comment: А почему курсив?

Comment: точка, если просьба, если сообщение, то восклицательный.

Answer (score 0):

• Я *предполагаю*, что правильно так (без знака вопроса):
***Позволь** проводить тебя, моя госпожа.*

*Позволь* — повелительное наклонение от "позволить", *моя госпожа* — обращение.
*Позволь проводить тебя, принцесса!* (С. Прокофьева. Три наследницы короля).

• А ещё так (с вопросительным знаком):
***Позволишь** проводить тебя, моя госпожа?*

*— Благодарю. Ты позволишь проводить тебя на сегодняшний бал, драгоценнейшая?* (Ю. Фирсанова. Родиться богиней).

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: ***Позволь проводить** тебя, моя госпожа.*

Вопросительный знак не нужен. Сравнить: *С твоего позволения, я провожу тебя, моя госпожа.*

**Пояснение**

1. Употребляется как **вежливая** форма обращения **при намерении** что-либо попросить, сказать.
2. Вопросительная форма возможна: *Ты **позволишь** проводить тебя, моя госпожа?*

**[Справочник по пунктуации](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_660)  .**   Тема: **С вашего позволения**, вводное выражение и члены предложения.